# How do I register a global mako function in pyramid from outside the template?

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

I'm building a pyramid application using mako templates.

How can I make a function be accessible in all my mako templates without having to `<%namespace />` a file in each and every template?

Not that having to add the namespace tag is bad per se, but in this case I'm trying to add a filter function (for markdown processing). That does not belong in a template file, but is more of a library thing and belongs in a .py file.

I want to write this in my mako template:

```
<div class="main-content">
    {page_content | markdown }
</div>
```

To state that `page_content` contains markdown code and should be processed as such.

Comment: You can also register global functions(helpers) that can be used in your templates as exaplined here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/templates/templates.html

Comment: @webjunkie I like your solution much better than mine. If you write an answer with `@subscriber(BeforeRender)` I'll accept that. That's what I'm using now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by @kratenko you can use a BeforeRender subscriber as detailed [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/templates/templates.html#using-a-beforerender-event-to-expose-a-mako-base-template)

You can add the following subscriber in your view

```
@subscriber(BeforeRender)
def add_base_template(event):
  request = event.get('request')
  if request.user:
    base = 'myapp:templates/logged_in_layout.mako'
    event.update({'base': base})
  else:
    base = 'myapp:templates/layout.mako'
    event.update({'base': base})
```

And in your mako template call it like so:

```
<%inherit file="${context['base']}" />
```

Comment: I'm using a `@subsriber(BeforeRender)` now, but differently: mine just has one line: `event['markdown'] = markdown`. Now I can use something line `<div>${page.text|n,markdown}</div>` to trigger markdown rendering in the template (as I did in [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32413231/1358283)). Your solution to make the function available is better, since that stuff does not belong in the config.ini.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify lines of python code, that should be included on the top of the modules, that will be created from your mako templates. This is intended for doing just this. As mako templates really translated to python modules, any name imported by this lines will be available as a name in your template. Filters are simply functions, that accept a string and return a new string (or unicode).

You can add a special module in your pyramid project to contain such functions, e.g. as `mako_imports.py`

```
# mako_imports.py
from markdown import markdown

def remove_all_a(text):
    # just a useless example for when you want to do 
    # something different with a custom function
    return text.replace('a', '')
```

Now, to include that functions, you add to your configuration files (`development.ini`, `production.ini`, ...) the following at your `mako.` section:

```
mako.imports = from <project_name>.mako_imports import markdown, remove_all_a
```

You need to specify the imports explicitly, as `from ... import *` is not supported there.

Now you should be able to do this in your mako templates:

```
<div class="main-content">
    ${page_content | n,markdown }
</div>
<div class="disfunct-main-content">
    ${page_content | remove_all_a }
</div>
```

And you should get rendered markdown (without any filtering for malicious html of course – be sure to take care of that if needed!). The additional `n` filter is needed, because by default mako would escape the created html.

<s>I think there must be a way to move the part in the .ini-files over to your program code (e.g. in the `main()` function of your application), but I did not figure that out yet.</s>

*Edit: there is a way, see accepted answer.*

Comment: You can in fact specify mako.imports in Python code by doing     `config.add_settings({"mako.imports": "from myproject.mako_imports import things"})` in your configuration funcion.

Comment: @MariusGedminas That looks nice and would be a valuable answer, if you posted it. I guess you could do it via your config file as well if you preferred?